# if order of G is $ p^2q^2r^2$ and nilpotent then it is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p,q,r$ be distinct primes. Show that any group $G$ of order $|G|=p^2q^2r^2$ is abelian if and only if it is nilpotent.

One side is trivial I see that... (if abelian then nilpotent) but other side... how I can show if it is nilpotent, then abelian?

Comment: A finite nilpotent group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, and all groups of order $p^2$ (with $p$ prime) are abelian.

Comment: Yes I know it, also nilpotent grouops have unique Sylow (dont it?) but does it show G is abelian? I think no

Comment: Yes it does, for the reason I just said! A direct product of abelian groups is abelian.

Comment: But if it is true, then directly all nilpotent are abelian..

Comment: Ok I see that.. Thank you:)

Comment: What we have proved is that all nilpotent groups whose order is not divisible by $p^3$ for any prime $p$ are abelian.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt I was confused but everytinhg is ok now :)